# Split html string with regex

Tags: javascript

It's possible to split an html string with regex like this one

```
var mystring="<p style='display:inline'>hello world</p>!!';
```

and obtain an array like this one?

```
[<p style='display:inline'>,hello world,</p>,!!]
```

UPDATE: I did it using the following regex

```
mystring.split(/(<\/?\w+(?:(?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>)/gim);
```

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by splitting it?  If you just want the text inside a <p> element, you can get it from one line of code using jQuery.

Comment: @jonathon I don't see a jquery tag... why is it everyone on SO always wants to get out the hammer to solve problems?

Comment: @Hemlock because jQuery is a toolbox, and we're bound by the [law of the instrument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument).

Comment: @jonathon I do not want the text, I need to split the variable with the html in objects in order to evaluate them later. If I do this with DOM(with or without framworks) the function returns an array of all the elements but it doesn't respect the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to post this answer because I think its a bad idea. This will not be the most durable solution, parsing html with regular expressions is just not a good idea. You should use the DOM. Here goes:

`mystring.replace(/>/g,'>\x1d').split(/(?=<)|\x1d/)`

Basically, replace all `>` with `>{group separator}` then do a lookahead split on `<` and a split on `{group separator}`. You get what you want, but it won't work if you have < or > or the group separator character unescaped inside your html anywhere.

Comment: At the end I find a solution using mystring.split(/(<\/?\w+(?:(?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>)/gim)

Comment: @Panchito Looks like a nightmare to support, but it does the job and doesn't have the same problems with > and < that mine does.